# Are “thought” and “had thought” both correct?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, past-tense

- I thought she had saved money.
- I had thought she saved money.

Is the 2nd sentence wrong?

Comment: They're both "correct".  They mean slightly different things, and context is needed to divine the precise meanings.

Answer (score 2):

Kino's right. Both could be correct, depending on the the time relationship of the thinking and the saving. Try adding a clause that more fully explains what happened.

Comment: To request clarification of the OP, please do so in a comment not an answer.